# Use of Supports() function with generic interface type

Tags: delphi, generics, interface

I just tried my first use of generics in Delphi 2009 and am perplexed on how to use a generic type as the input to the Supports function used to see if an object implements a given interface.  I've created a small sample illustrating the problem.

Given the following types and utility function:

```
IMyInterface = interface
['{60F37191-5B95-45BC-8C14-76633826889E}']
end;

TMyObject = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
end;

class function TFunctions.GetInterface<T>(myObject: TObject): T;
var
  specificInterface: T;
begin
  // This would compile, but looses the generic capability
  //Supports(myObject, IMyInterface, specificInterface);

  // This results in compile errors
  Supports(myObject, T, specificInterface);

  result := specificInterface;
end;
```

and the following code snippet:

```
class procedure TFunctions.Test;
var
  myObject: TMyObject;
  myInterface: IMyInterface;
begin
  myObject := TMyObject.Create;

  myInterface := GetInterface<IMyInterface>(myObject);
end;
```

I would expect no problems but I get the following compile time errors:

> [DCC Error] GenericExample.pas(37): E2029 '(' expected but ',' found
>   [DCC Error] GenericExample.pas(37): E2014 Statement expected, but expression of type 'T' found

I'm not sure what the compiler is expecting me to do with the T when used as the actual argument to the function.

I've searched around quite a bit and haven't been able to crack this one. A part of me suspects that if I could understand how an interface name gets converted to the IID: TGUID type during compilation, when using a concrete interface name, I could make some headway, but that has evaded me also.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no guarantee that T has a GUID associated with it, and there is no means in the language to write a constraint on the type parameter to make that guarantee.

The interface name is converted into a GUID by the compiler looking up the name in the symbol table, getting the compiler's data structure representing the interface, and checking the corresponding field for the GUID. But generics are not like C++ templates; they need to be compiled and type-checked and known to work for any valid type parameter, and that means constraining the type parameter in its declaration.

You can get the GUID using RTTI (first checking that T does indeed represent an interface) with something like `GetTypeData(TypeInfo(T))^.Guid` and pass the GUID to `Supports` that way.

Comment: can you not apply a constraint that T must be some specified interface which has a GUID?

Comment: If it needs to be some interface, then the code isn't generic. Supports will return an interface reference; the compiler can't generically turn that into whatever T is.

Comment: Barry, thanks for your help.  Most of my experience with generic programming has been from a C++ background, and I expected that the compiler would know if an interface has a Guid the same way it would know if the interface name were provided directly.  It makes perfect sense now knowing that generics <> C++ templates. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you even bothering?

To use this TFunctions.GetInterface you need:

- an interface
- an object reference

If you have those, then you can just call Supports() directly:

```
  intf := TFunctions.GetInterface<IMyInterface>(myObject);
```

is *exactly* equivalent to:

```
  Supports(IMyInterface, myObject, intf);
```

Using generics here is a waste of time and effort and really begs the question "Why Do It?".

It is just making things harder to read (as is so often the case with generics) and is more cumbersome to use.

**Supports()** returns a convenient boolean to indicate success/failure, which you have to test for separately using your wrapper:

```
  intf := TFunctions.GetInterface<IMyInterface>(myObject);
  if Assigned(intf) then
    // ...
```

versus:

```
  if Supports(IMyInterface, myObject, intf) then
    // We can use intf
```

When creating wrappers around functionality it is generally the case that the result is an improvement in readabilty or usability.

imho this fails on both counts and you should just stick with the **Supports()** function itself.

Comment: My example is distilled from the actual context, to ask a specific question, and is not illustrative of the actual design.

Comment: Then you need to provide at least SOME of the context.  Otherwise it's like asking how to get from A to B without mentioning that you can't drive and don't have money for a bus fare.  It may be that even in the context, what you are doing is not the best/easiest way of going about it.  It's all well and good asking a specific question, but if you want helpful answers then it's no good throwing out important context.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Cheers.

Comment: As is your right.  Good luck with whatever you are doing.  We can only hope that you aren't wasting your time.  ;)

Comment: GetInterface is not exactly the same as Supports. The latter will try to retrieve an IUnknown interface which might succeed, while GetInterface will only return an interface if it's the exact type of interface being queried.

Comment: @user1061947 what are you talking about ?   Supports will try to retrieve the **specified** interface, not IUnknown, and will only succeed (return TRUE) if that specified interface is **supported**.  GetInterface can in fact only provide the specific interface if Supports does this since the implementation is trying to *use* Supports to implement GetInterface&lt;T&gt; !!!

Comment: @Deltics, check implementation of Supports function in System.pas unit and you will see that it first tries to retrieve an IUnknown interface, and only then it calls IUknonwn.QueryInterface to retrieve the actual desired interface.

Comment: @user1061947 (_Delphi XE4, in SysUtils.pas not System.pas_). Yes, it attempts to obtain `IUnknown` but even if this is successful it still only returns TRUE if a call to the overloaded `Supports()` fn using that (locally held) unknown ref **ALSO** supports the requested specific interface.  `Supports()` will not return TRUE if the specific interface is not supported, even if `IUnknown` is.  In addition, regardless of the directly returned **result** value, the "worker" `IUnknown` ref it obtains is never exposed to the caller since this is only ever held in a local var.

Comment: @Deltics, the problem is not returning true. The problem is that once that IUnknown is locally retrieved, when it's out of scope it will decrement reference count and - even if it doesn't implement the desired interface - destroy the object (If the object was manually created before and thus reference count was zero)