# Generic parameter to define the interface the generic class is implementing

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Is it possible to have a generic parameter to define the interface a class is implementing?
Or does anyone have an explanation, why Delphi does not allow this (Or am I just doing it wrong?):

```
TInterfacedMyWrapper<T: IInterface> = class(TMyWrapper, T)
    function PropGetIntf(): T;
    property Intf: T read PropGetIntf implements T;
end;
```

This yields the following errors:

- `E2205: Interface type required`
- `E2259: Implements clause only allowed for properties of class or interface type`

This is my workaround:

```
TInterfacedMyWrapper<T: IInterface> = class(TMyWrapper)
    function PropGetIntf(): T;
    property Intf: T read PropGetIntf;
end;

TIFooMyWrapper = class(TInterfacedMyWrapper<IFoo>, IFoo)
    property Intf: IFoo read PropGetIntf implements IFoo;
end;
```

But this forces me to define a separate class for every interface. I'ld rather like to write:

```
TInterfacedMyWrapper<IFoo>.Create(CompToWrap);
```

**Edited** (some more context to explain my goals - I hope it is not too confusing...):

I have multiple classes derived from `TFooComp`, that cannot be modified. And I have a wrapper class `TMyWrapper`, that inherits from `TBarBase`. I cannot modify `TBarBase`. 
`TMyWrapper` is a wrapper for `TFooComp` (kind of adapter pattern).

Every `TFooComp`-derived class may expose an interface. What I would like to reach is, that `TInterfacedMyWrapper` exposes that interface too (and delegates it to the
wrapped `TFooComp`).

This is working somehow:

```
constructor TMyWrapper.CreateNew(AOwner: TComponent; FooClass: TFooClass);
begin
    FWrappedFooComp := FooClass.Create(Self);
    //...
end;

//...

function TInterfacedMyWrapper<T>.PropGetIntf(): T;
begin
    //see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418278/use-of-supports-function-with-generic-interface-type
    if not Supports(FWrappedFooComp, GetTypeData(TypeInfo(T))^.Guid, Result) then
      raise Exception.Create('Interface not implemented');
end;
```

But for every `TFooComp`-derived class I have to create an own wrapper class (with just one declaration):

```
TWrappedFooXxx = class(TInterfacedMyWrapper<IXxx>, Ixxx)
    property Intf: IXxx read PropGetIntf implements IXxx;
end;
```

that I can use the following way:

```
Result := TWrappedFooXxx.CreateNew(Owner, TFooXxx);
Result.DoSomething();
(Result as IXxx).DoSomeMore();
```

The necessity to create an own wrapper class is, what I try to avoid. I would rather only write:

```
Result := TInterfacedMyWrapper<IXxx>.CreateNew(Owner, TFooXxx);
Result.DoSomething();
(Result as IXxx).DoSomeMore();
```

Comment: A small but complete sample program would have been better because then we would not have to guess the types of some things (like inherits `TBarBase` from `TInterfacedObject` or not, or what type is `Result` in your last two snippets)

Comment: @StefanGlienke The real code, is code, I wanted to publish anyway. I just wanted to check this question before publishing. I tried to post this question in a way, that it is not to narrow. But you are right. I will clean up the real code, publish it, provide a link and provide a sample program here. (Regarding your questions: `TBarBase` and `TMyWrapper` inherit from `TComponent`, thus implementing `IInterface`. The type of `Result` is determined by the constructor `CreateNew` derived from TMyWrapper).

Answer (score 2):

> why Delphi does not allow this?

Because this is not C++ templates. The compiler in Delphi needs to know the interfaces your class is implementing (although it is generic). But in this case it cannot because you are trying to implement a not yet known interface.

Comment: OK, this explains, why the syntax, I used, wont work (btw I tried to find an "official" reference for your claim, but could not find one?). But the existence of `TVirtualInterface` makes me believe, that it is not entirely impossible to implement an interface, that is not known to the class at compile time. `TInterfacedMyWrapper<IFoo>.Create(CompToWrap) as IFoo` would be nice to have, too ;)

Comment: I am wondering what you were trying to achieve, because `CompToWrap` is clearly not of type `T` because then you get nowhere even if it would work with the generic because you could only just return the wrapped instance in `PropGetIntf` but not add any custom code to it (like a decorator pattern would do). Please provide a bit more context to your question

Comment: I believe he's trying to dynamically add interface support to a class that has all the method declared for the interface, but didn't declare itself as supporting said interface.  Something like `TWrap<IStreamPersist>.Create(TStringList.Create)` (Granted, TStringList doesn't support IUnknown, but you get the idea?)

Comment: The interface delegation clause is confusing me if that was his approach.

Comment: @StefanGlienke I have edited the question to provide more details. My wrapper class is an adapter for the base component, that allows to use the base component in a different context. But the wrapper class shall expose the same interface as the wrapped class.

Comment: I cannot and will not provide an update unless you write down all code necessary to give an answer. As long as I don't know your exact class hierarchy and what types the things in your code snippets it is impossible to provide a solution.

Comment: I understand. I will update the code. But I need some time to clean up things.