# Generic function with interface constraint

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Why does the following code:

```
TYPE
  TFmxObjHelper = CLASS HELPER FOR TFmxObject
                    FUNCTION    GetInterface<T:IInterface> : T;
                  END;

FUNCTION TFmxObjHelper.GetInterface<T> : T;
  BEGIN
    IF NOT Supports(Self,T,Result) THEN Result:=NIL // Error on this line
  END;
```

produce `E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Supports' that can be called with these arguments` ?

And how should it be written in order to have a "`GetInterface`" mehod that either returns the specified interface (if the object implements it) or NIL (if the object doesn't)?

Comment: You can pass `GetTypeData(TypeInfo(T))^.GUID` to the second parameter. Actually, [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4418278/8041231) has been asked in the past.

Comment: @Victoria: Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!